# Как добавить сортировку процессов в диспетчере задач по алф. и и т.д?

Tags: c#, winforms, сортировка, вкладки

Собственно в C# WinForms, нужно добавить в дисп. задач эти вкладки и сортировку процессов - по алф, сортировку памяти - по убыванию и состояние. Что вообще это за вкладки? Как их добавить?

[image: Вкладки выделены]

Comment: это заголовки колонок GridView, ничего добавлять не надо, они там есть, нужно только колонки добавить и настроить правильно. Примеры в MSDN есть. Попробуйте сделать самостоятельно и добавьте в вопрос что не получилось.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx#Примеры

Answer (score 0):

Все, разобрался. Вот что сделал

```
        ListViewItem row;
        proces = Process.GetProcesses();
        if (Convert.ToInt32(label2.Text) != proces.Length)
        {
            LstProc.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < proces.Length; i++)
            {
                row = new ListViewItem(proces[i].ProcessName); // Создаем переменную row для обращения к ней, при добавлении суб айтемов.
                row.SubItems.Add((proces[i].VirtualMemorySize64 / 2048).ToString() + " КБ");
                row.SubItems.Add("Работает");
                row.SubItems.Add(proces[i].SessionId.ToString());
                LstProc.Items.Add(row);
                List<ListViewItem> arrayToDelete = new List<ListViewItem>();
                  for (int j = 0; j < LstProc.Items.Count; j++)
                   if (LstProc.Items[j].SubItems[2].Text == "*")
                       arrayToDelete.Add(LstProc.Items[j]);
                      foreach (ListViewItem delete in arrayToDelete)
                   LstProc.Items.Remove(delete);
            }
            label2.Text = proces.Length.ToString();
        }
    }'
```